# Proof of the well ordering principle without mathematical induction

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic, induction

Is it possible to prove the well ordering principle without using mathematical induction? If yes, how?

Comment: Depends on what axioms you are assuming. If you use ZFC, it's possible. If you use something like Peano arithmetic, then well-ordering principle cannot be even expressed.

Comment: @Giuseppe Rossi What a coincidence, your name is also very similar to Giuseppe Peano.